# What should I do when two clauses that must be in parenthesis sit next to each other in my sentence?

Tags: parentheses, technical

I'm writing my thesis dissertation and in the results section I'm showing my results with this sentence:

> A small correlation  between hit position and time was found for SS2 ($r=-0.143, p<0.01$) but not for SS1 ($p>0.05$) (see Figure 3.2).

I believe I'm following APA guidelines for reporting statistical results and I want to show the reader the figure as it shows graphically my results. But, I don't like having these two parentheses next to each other. What can I do?

Comment: Don't do anything. That's perfectly fine.

Comment: But if you don't like it rewrite it:  As shown in Figure 3.2, a small correlation ...

Comment: Is 'two (sets of) parentheses next to each other' against APA guidelines?

Comment: It looks OK to me, but I'd probably omit the parentheses around "see Figure 3.2" and put a semicolon before "see".

Comment: Rewriting is probably the best solution.  Anything else develops into a religious argument.  (If it weren't a thesis it wouldn't be such a big deal, but you never can predict the religion of those reviewing it.)

Answer (score 1):

Keep the double parenthesis. Their separate meaning is clear, and the reader can make separate decisions to elide them in their reading or not as appropriate to them.

Answer (score 1):

From the 6th edition of the APA handbook:

back to back.
Correct:
(e.g., defensive pessimism; Norem & Cantor, 1986)

Incorrect:
(e.g., defensive pessimism) (Norem & Cantor, 1986)